# ERROR: Unable to parse " ": Unexpected token (JSDoc)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

I have defined the class,property, methods as per the documentation of JsDoc, but I am getting the error as: Unable to parse "/somePath":Unexpected token.My class definition are as like this:-

```
/**
 * class representing Lab testResults
 * @param {object} props: contain all the property
 */
class LabTestResult extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
        }
        this.collapseButton = this.collapseButton.bind(this);
    }
    state = {
        open: false,
    };
}
```

Why I am getting this error? How can I solve this? please assist me.

Comment: `state = {open: false};` is not valid in ES6 there. I wouldn't expect jsdoc to support every experimental feature.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a vanilla 2015 class, here's a sample (from the docs). I don't think the "class" annotation takes parameters. Anyway, this is the way it says to "document a simple es2015 class". Note the params are above the constructor, not the class. I've never been a JSDoc wizard but that looked incorrect.

From here: http://usejsdoc.org/howto-es2015-classes.html

```
/**
 * Class representing a dot.
 * @extends Point
 */
class Dot extends Point {
    /**
     * Create a dot.
     * @param {number} x - The x value.
     * @param {number} y - The y value.
     * @param {number} width - The width of the dot, in pixels.
     */
    constructor(x, y, width) {
        // ...
    }

    /**
     * Get the dot's width.
     * @return {number} The dot's width, in pixels.
     */
    getWidth() {
        // ...
    }
}
```